# How to link a 3rd party lib to a static library target in cmake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, linker

I want to cmake a project like this:

```
Foo/
   |- libFoo/
         |- CMakeLists.txt                  
         |- foo.h
         |- foo.cpp
   |- libFooTests/
         |- CMakeLists.txt
         |- test.cpp
   |- CMakeLists.txt

# Foo/CMakeLists.txt
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(Foo)
# I'm on windows, so make sure that all projects are using same runtime library
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd"
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT"
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(libFoo)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(libFooTests)

# Foo/libFoo/CMakeLists.txt
ADD_LIBRARY(libFoo foo.h foo.cpp)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${THIRD_PARTY_LIB_DIR})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(libFoo lib3rdparty)

# Foo/libFooTests/CMakeLists.txt
ADD_EXECUTABLE(libFooTests test.cpp)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libFoo")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(libFooTests libFoo)
```

if I run cmake on this setup, project can be successfully generated. But it fails to build because the project generated was configured to link `lib3rdparty` to the test target `libFooTests` instead of `libFoo` and of course `libFooTests` can't know (and shouldn't know) where to find `lib3rdparty`.

I tried this both on windows (using generator "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64") and on Ubuntu (using generator "Unix Makefiles").

#### What I expected:

`${THIRD_PARTY_LIB_DIR}` should be configured as library search path to `libFoo` target and `lib3rdparty` should be configured as library input for `libFoo`
`libFooTests` only knows where to include headers of `libFoo` (aka. `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libFoo` ) and links `libFoo`. It shouldn't know anything about `lib3rdparty`

#### What acutally happend:

`${THIRD_PARTY_LIB_DIR}` seems to be ignored.
`lib3rdparty` is a library input for `libTests`

#### What I noticed:

I noticed the `Properties Page` dialogs of `libFoo.vcxproj` and `libFooTests.vcxproj` in visual studio are slightly different.

The former one has a `Configuration Properties | Librarian` entry while the latter one has a `Configuration Properties | Linker` instead.

How can I link `lib3rdparty` to `libFoo` only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Static libraries don't get linked. A static library is just a bunch of object files packaged up into one file.

The linking happens when you link them with a complete program. So if your static library relies on another library, you have to link that library into all programs that use your static library. CMake seems to be doing the right thing here by doing this automatically.

Comment: I see. Is there any approach to achieve something similar? making `libFoo` shared etc.

Comment: Given "static libs don't get linked", the most proper way here may be let `libFooTests` know where to find those libs "inherited" from `libFoo`. Puting `LINK_DIRECTORIES` into `libFooTests/CMakeLists.txt` would work, but it's really nasty to do that. How can I make `LINK_DIRECTORIES` also be "inherited" to the `libFooTests` ?